# Mobile Safari browsing - elements not displaying but marked with '=$0'

Tags: jquery, css, safari, mobile-safari

I am getting ready to put a website live, but am having a strange issue in mobile Safari - whereby certain content on the page does not display. When inspecting those elements, the HTML markup has the following added to the end of the code -  `= $0`

For example:

```
<header> = $0
</header>
```

The issue only occurs when navigating between pages, the first load (and if you refresh) appear to be OK.

I have little idea where to begin to debug this problem, so any advice would be greatly received. Could it be jQuery related?

[Link](http://oakdesignstudio.com)

Comment: Safari is trying to help you refer to the element you selected.  See this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217509/why-does-0-appear-in-safari-web-inspector